# Prevent Bottom Sheet Covering Bottom App Bar

Tags: bottom-sheet, android-bottomappbar

I have a BottomAppBar in my activity and a BottomNavigationFragment that extends BottomSheetDialogFragment.

## MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setSupportActionBar(bottom_app_bar)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        when (item!!.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                val bottomNavDrawerFragment = BottomNavigationFragment()
                bottomNavDrawerFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, bottomNavDrawerFragment.tag)
            }
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

## activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/baseline_menu_white_24"/>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_white_24"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The problem is when bottom sheet collapses, it covers BottomAppBar.
I want to it open behind the BottomAppBar.